# Problems installing virtualenvwrapper - No module named virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

I trying install virtualenvwrapper from your official guide http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html

I install virtualenvwrapper with pip and when I define the environment variables and source

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I reboot my shell and I get the following output.

```
bgarcial@el-pug:~$ bash
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named virtualenvwrapper
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
bgarcial@el-pug:~$
```

Despite this, the commands mkvirtualenv and others works. But .. What does this mean? How I can fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is the content of your ~/.bashrc file?

You may be calling "virtualenvwrapper" instead of "virtualenvwrapper.sh"

OR:

You may be exporting variables for the current shell that don't persist or propagate to subsequent shells.

The following script will install virtualenvwrapper and configure bash to persist the environment variables, which should in turn make virtualenvwrapper work as expected.

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper

configure_bashrc(){
echo '
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
' >> ~/.bashrc

source ~/.bashrc
}

[[ -z $(grep virtualenv ~/.bashrc) ]] && configure_bashrc
```

Comment: Hi OkeziE, this is the content of my /etc/bash.bashrc file         export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$IDEA_JDK/bin:$PATH
export WORKON_HOME=/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs 
export PROJECT_HOME=/home/bgarcial/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
I have been test the mkproject command which should will be create and virtual environment and the project in my PROJECT_HOME directory, but, only create the virtual env nothing.  How to can I install virtualenvwrapper correctly? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I have been configuring my environment variables in my bash and I've recently setup my virtualenvwrapper environment.

Comment: Great to hear that your environment is all set up.  Did you find what the initial issue was?

Comment: Yes, I think it was not define good this environment variables    export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source $VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT 
Although in this opportunnity, I install zsh shell and oh-my-zsh, and even the procedure is the same that bash, all it's works. Thanks for the recommendations and your attention :)